# maven eclipse:eclipse - how to bring certain dependencies as jar files

Tags: eclipse, maven

I do have a multi module project out of which one references few others in the workspace. When  I do maven eclipse:eclipse, it generates the .classpath with references to dependent projects as folder names (given below).

I understand that to generate all the dependent projects to be available as jar files in the classpath, we have to use 'useProjectReferences'. However, I need the classpath entry for  child-project1 to be available as path to the jar file in the m2_repo and leave the classpath entry to child-project2 as reference to the folder.

Comment: Better use m2e and import your project into Eclipse. Check if your project works correctly from command line mvn clean package .

Comment: The project works fine while building from command line. Would I be able to refer the referenced project as jar if I import the project?

Answer (score 1):

Do a clean install of your referenced projects. Right click your parent project ->  properties->maven, uncheck 'reference projects from workspace'. See if this works.

Comment: This actually will change all the dependencies from referenced folders to deployed packages. My project is dependent on multiple projects in the same workspace. I need only one of them to be referenced as jars. Otherwise, every change in the child project would need a maven compile to get the changes reflected in the parent